# Starting a service and activity at same instance

Tags: android, android-layout

From a activity onClick event need to start an activity and a service also.
I have implemented that. But problem is that service is starting but activity is not loading properly. Only blank screen is coming. Sorry message is coming "Application is not responding" and asking me to either to wait or force close it.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startService(new Intent(NewUIM.this, MyService.class));
            Intent i = new Intent(NewUIM.this, NewUI.class);
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in your question for anyone to be able to help you. You need to post some code.

Comment: there has to be a useful stack trace too, please look it up in your logcat, and share it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `AsynTask` while the `Service` is running and implement the `Activity` . For more information, check the link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html